# How can i make a code run automatically every 30 mins in shell script or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, shell, cron

I have a code which I want to run every 30mins. Since it is not possible to do it manually over 30 days I wanted to make it an automated process. Please suggest me how to do it. I want to execute this command in Putty.

```
--user root --host 10.0.2.140 --port 3306 --socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: That's not a command. That's just arguments to the mysql client. (And starting that will not do much on its own.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/), your entry would look like this:

*/30 * * * * /path/to/your/command

Comment: To edit the crontab the command is usually `crontab -e`. More info on how to use the crontab command can by found by entering the command `man crontab`

Answer (score 3):

Unix and derivatives use Cron Jobs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Windows uses scheduled tasks.

https://superuser.com/questions/85297/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-windows-7

Note that there are also some Cron clone implementations for windows available if you prefer.

Comment: Let me rephrase, I need the shell script syntax which could run that command. The actual code